# ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"] is blank when using Windows Authentication in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I have an ASP MVC 4 application which uses a 3rd party HTTP module for security. When using Windows authentication it will attempt to automatically log you in, if that fails, then it will redirect you to a custom login page.

This has been working fine for previous ASP Webforms and MVC 2-4  applications, but for this particular application it is failing to automatically log the user in.

The application's virtual directory has all of the authentication modes disabled (anonymous etc) except for Windows authentication which is enabled. I have also checked that the provider is *Negotiate* and *NTLM*.

The web.config is a pretty standard one that you get from the MVC template and I have tried various web.config changes to `system.web` and `system.webServer` (and changing app pool's pipeline mode) such as:

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

and also adding

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

But in each case the security module cannot get the user name. The module attempts to get the user name via `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"]`, but I have also modified it to use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` and in both cases it is blank.

Since this module has been working fine for years and still works for other applications on the same server, I believe it is an IIS or Web.config configuration issue. I have tried creating a new virtual directory and it has the same error.

Is there any additional configuration required or another reason why it is not working for this particular application?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the following to my the `appSetting` section in my web.config

```
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
```

This is the first time that I have needed to add such a thing, so I am not sure why it is necessary, but it does work.